# extract chimeric and multimap reads from bam file

Tags: sam, htslib

I am trying to extract all chimeric and multi-map reads from either SAM/BAM file. Is there any simple command to do that? Can I use `htslib` for parsing sam/bam files and extracting based on any flags. Any help on how to start will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it.

```
samtools view -@5 -f 0x800 -hb /path/sample.bam > sup.bam
```

Then if you want it as a fasta

```
samtools view -F 0x1 -hb sup.bam | samtools fasta -F 0x1 - > sup.fa
```

Comment: Thanks !! It works great. I will use samtools source code to write a small program to extract the reads based on flag.

Comment: Pysam wraps it pretty well, just fyi